# FOR UPDATE CURSOR in teradata?

Tags: teradata, plsqldeveloper

This is sql block i'm using in Oracle,

> Now I need to do the same way in Teradata, Is possible? I want the syntax FOR UPDATE CURSOR in Teradata!

Can you please guide me?

```
declare
cursor c1 is select * from  Employees  FOR UPDATE;
a number :=0 ; 
begin
for x in c1 loop
   a := a +1 ; 
    update  employees  set salary = a  where current of c1;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you want such a cursor? This is equivalent to starting a transaction and keeping it open while a user goes for coffe. Such thing are death for scalability. A far better option (in Oracle as well) is to use optimistic concurrency. As for the loop, it simply negates any performance benefit provided by using a database

Answer (score 1):

Updateable cursors are allowed in ANSI-mode sessions only.

The syntax is quite similar:

```
declare c1 cursor for
  select * from  Employees  FOR UPDATE;
a number :=0 ; 
begin
for x in c1 loop
   a := a +1 ; 
    update  employees  set salary = a  where current of c1;
end loop;
end;
```

But cursors perform really bad in a parallel DBMS like Teradata as they're processed serially, one row after the other.

In almost every case cursors on data can be rewritten set-based (e.g. your example is a simple ROW_NUMBER) and then they perform several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Cursors and loops perform atrociously in any database, not just a parallel one. The Oracle code could run a few thousand times faster too if an UPDATE with ROW_NUMBER was used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Of course cursors are always bad, it's just even worse when you got a massive parallel system with multiple servers and the process does a `FETCH NEXT` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this instead?

```
UPDATE employees
FROM (
  SELECT csum(1,1) new_salary, emp_id
  FROM employees 
) src
set salary=src.new_salary  
where employees.emp_id=src.emp_id;
```

Comment: but in the above code, emp_id should be a unique index or primary key. If there is not unique column in the sense, How can I achieve this?